# sleep in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, sleep

### script A

```
    (insert (current-time-string))
    (sleep-for 5)
    (insert (current-time-string))
```

`M-x eval-buffer`, two time strings are inserted with 5 secs apart

### script B

some comint code (that add hook, and start process)

```
    (sleep-for 60) ;delay a bit for process to finish
    (insert "ZZZ")
```

`M-x eval-buffer`, "ZZZ" is inserted right away, without any time delay

what might have happened? btw, it's Emacs 23.2 on Win XP

Comment: Happens to me too. sleep-for seems to be sometimes ignored in batch mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you want to do is to wait for a process to finish, you should probably not use `sleep-for` at all. Instead call the process synchronously, not asynchronously:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html#Synchronous-Processes

This way, Emacs will block until the process has finished.

If you must (or really want to) use an asynchronous process, for instance because it takes very long and you don't want Emacs to freeze during that time (you speak of 60 seconds, which is quite long), then the right way to wait for the process to finish is by using a [sentinel](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html#Sentinels). A sentinel is a callback that gets called whenever the status of a process changes, e.g., when it terminates.

```
(defun my-start-process ()
  "Returns a process object of an asynchronous process."
  ...)

(defun my-on-status-change (process status)
  "Callback that receives notice for every change of the `status' of `process'."
  (cond ((string= status "finished\n") (insert "ZZZ"))
        (t (do-something-else))))

;; run process with callback
(let ((process (my-start-process)))
  (when process
    (set-process-sentinel process 'my-on-status-change)))
```

Comment: The sample code and the link are great, I tried and synchronous process and it works fine for me, though the 60 sec wait is a bit long. Thanks a lot, Thomas.

Answer (score 12):

It probably interrupted the sleep to deal with the subprocess IO.  You should really use something like `run-with-idle-timer` for such "delay a bit for process" things, since Emacs is single-threaded.

Comment: I didn't know Emacs is single-threaded. Thanks for the quick response. I read about run-with-idle-timer and think maybe I should use synchronous process in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Waiting.html) it might be implemented *not only* by **'sleep-for** but by the **'sit-for** also:

```
(defun smart-translate ()
  "Shows translation of a word at the current point
at the full frame for several seconds and 
returns to the initial buffer"
  (interactive)
  (google-translate-at-point)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Google Translate*")
  (delete-other-windows)
  (sit-for 5)
  (previous-buffer)
  )
```