# Get result back from comint-redirect-send-command

Tags: emacs, comint-mode

I want to read the output of a buffer after process started by comint finishes.

```
(comint-redirect-send-command-to-process 
                 command-string ;; tested to work in the commint buffer
                 output-buffer-name ;; random text
                 buffer-process ;; (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
                 nil ;; don't echo input back
                 t) ;; don't show output buffer immediatly
```

This sexp is evaluated in a buffer running a comint process. I want to read all the text of `output-buffer-name` once the process has finished.

I have tried applying the solution posted to this question: [sleep in emacs lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578373/sleep-in-emacs-lisp#6580546) by adding this below the process start command:

```
(defun on-status-change (process status)
        (message "status done"))

(set-process-sentinel buffer-process 'on-status-change)
```

This message does not appear in `*Messages*`.

There is no prompt in the output-buffer text, but I can write a function that returns `t` when the output is finished based on the full output text.

How can I react to the buffer finishing/changing, or how can I force comint to run this function synchronously.

---

The source for `comint-redirect-send-command-to-process` is [here on line 3717](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/comint.el#n3717)

Comment: The comint-redi.... function returns `t`

Comment: You're setting a sentinel on the comint process. If you send a command to that process, you can't expect to get a status change for the comint process sentinel at the completion of the inferior command which was sent to that process. The comint process is still running.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has a similar issue, I ended up "solving" this.

```
(while (not comint-redirect-completed)
  (sleep-for 0.01))
```

> `comint-redirect-completed`’s value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil if redirection has completed in the current buffer.

Obviously not a great solution, but I couldn't get anything else working.

Comment: Also consider this pattern, from [sql.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/a1386fa/lisp/progmodes/sql.el#L3988-L3989):
```(while (or quit-flag (null comint-redirect-completed))
  (accept-process-output nil 1)))```